# Can I share an object between telegram commands of a bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to create an object when the user press /start in a Telegram bot, and then share this object among all the commands of the bot. Is this possible? As far as I understand, there's only one thread of your bot running in your server. However, I see that there is a context in the command functions. Can I pass this object as a kind of context? For example:

```
'''
This is a class object that I created to store data from the user and configure the texts I'll display depending on
the user language but maybe I fill it also with info about something it will buy in the bot
'''
import configuration 

from telegram import Update, ForceReply
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext

# Commands of the bot
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    s = configuration.conf(update) #Create the object I'm saying
    update.message.reply_markdown_v2(s.text[s.lang_active],
        reply_markup=ForceReply(selective=True),
    )

def check(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    s = configuration.conf(update)   # I want to avoid this!
    update.message.reply_markdown_v2(s.text[s.lang_active],
        reply_markup=ForceReply(selective=True),
    )

... REST OF THE BOT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python-telegram-bot` already comes with a [built-in mechanism for storing data](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Storing-bot%2C-user-and-chat-related-data). You can do something like

```
try:
    s = context.user_data['config']
except KeyError:
    s = configuration.confi(update)
    context.user_data['config'] = s
```

This doesn't have to be repeated in every callback - you can e.g.

- use a [`TypeHandler` in a low group](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Frequently-requested-design-patterns#how-to-handle-updates-in-several-handlers) to create the config if needed. then in all handlers in higher groups, you don't need to worry about it
- use a [custom implementation of `CallbackContext`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/v13.x/examples/contexttypesbot.py) that adds a property `context.user_config`

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.